# :nth-of-type selector overrides all other CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I am trying to revise for my exam on HTML, JavaScript and CSS3; and I am a little confused at CSS selectors and which take priority.

I have the following CSS:

```
table                   { border: 1px solid black; }
tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color: red; }
tr td:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: blue; }
td                      { background-color: green; }
```

I thought that whatever comes last takes priority, so in my opinion all cells in the table would be green.

However the even cells are still blue, as per the nth-of-type selector.  Even when I put this to the top and remove the green td line, the blue is still shown in the middle with only the odd cells showing in red.

Can someone explain why the nth-of-type seems to take precedent over everything else?

Here is the example:

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: red; }
tr td:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: blue; }
td { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6157xwz/

Comment: Well I think you have your answer with regards to specificity being the issue here.  This also why you typically see experienced CSS developers, placing more specific rules within one specific section of CSS after more general rules. It makes the intended behavior of what you are writing more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule with the blue is more specific and that is why it takes precedence.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: The w3 spec is here: [http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

Answer (score 7):

### So what's this?

What's going on here is **[selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**.

> The following list of selector types is by **increasing** specificity:
>
> 1. Universal selectors (e.g. `*`)
> 2. Type selectors (e.g. `h1`)
>    Class selectors (e.g. `.example`)
>    Attribute selectors (e.g. `[type="radio"]`)
> 3. Pseudo-classes (e.g., `:hover`)
> 4. ID selectors (e.g. `#example`)
> 5. Inline style (e.g. `style="font-weight:bold"`)

### Simplified explanation for your code

In your example, the pseudo selector `:nth-of-type(even/odd)` is category 3 which takes precedence since the concurring selectors are only `type selectors` (category 2.1).

### Important note

Deviating from MDN information available behind that link, I have corrected that type, class and attribute selectors actually have the same specificity.

Comment: So how in this example would I get red rows, but then blue only in the even columns of the even rows?

Comment: Actually I think I have worked it out: tr:nth-of-type(even) td:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: blue; }, is that correct?

Comment: Your CSS is at least confusing. Please describe in detail what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @user3284707 the examples on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity explain this in more detail.

Comment: Until MDN fixes its specificity list please refrain from quoting that article. It implies that classes, attributes and pseudo-classes have different specificity values, which they do not. As others have mentioned the spec is much more accurate, it being the authoritative resource, even if it's less accessible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to order, but to accuracy.
The first selector is one selector of a type, the second selector is a selector of type and then specifies a filter while the third specifies two types and a filter.

The more accurate the selector, the more priority. Declaring order only matters when two (or more) selectors are evenly accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much, this now makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Typically this is referred to as specificity, not accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) of your selectors. There are two rules that match `td` elements. Their [calculated specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/) is:

```
tr td:nth-of-type(even) -> 0,0,1,2
td                      -> 0,0,0,1
```

The rule with higher specificity wins regardless of source order.