# With jQuery, how to remove the nth-of-type pseudo selector that is applied

Tags: jquery, css

I have this css:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #595049;
}
.simple {
    background-color: #3535f866;
}
```

Once the whole HTMLL page is drawn, I get some Json, and create a `table`, then for each row, I call this function:

```
var cbCreatedRow = function( row, data, dataIndex){
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('x') && !data.x) {
        $(row).addClass('simple');
    }
};
```

However, the first one "overrides" the simple class `simple` and I don't to want to smash it with the `!important` dirty solution. Note: I've already [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853755/nth-of-type-selector-overrides-all-other-css-selectors) but there's no solution.

Is there a way to remove, with jQuery, a pseudo class selector that is applied?

Comment: Can you include some HTML and exactly which element you're targetting?

Comment: Seems you could do `.table-striped>tbody>tr.simple:nth-of-type(odd)` but unclear without know where .simple is applied in relation the tr

Comment: Do you have access & can modify both selectors?

Comment: *Is there a way to remove, with jQuery, a pseudo class selector*  - jquery cannot target :pseudo elements as they are not part of the DOM, they're part of the styling.  It should be easy enough to add an additional rule to your `.simple` that adds *more specificity*, which is where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for jquery, this is a css solution / issue.

Your problem is due to *specificity* - in css, an entry with more rules has higher priority over one with fewer rules.

So `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)` has more rules that `.simple` so takes priority and you don't get the "simple" background rule.

The solution is to add the same rules to your `.simple` css entry:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd).simple,
.simple {
    ...
```

Sample snippet:

```js
$("button").click(() => {

  $("table tr").eq(0).addClass("simple");
  $("table tr").eq(1).addClass("simple");

});
```

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #595049;
}

.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd).simple,
.simple {
  background-color: #3535f866;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='table-striped'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button>click me</button>
```